# Selenium switch to popup window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When clicking a radio button, a new popup window opens and Selenium is unable to locate any elements from the new popup window. How do I switch Selenium to the new popup window, or extract the URL of the popup window?

```
print(driver.current_url)
```

retrieves the URL of the old tab and not the popup window.

```
print(driver.title)
```

prints the title of the old tab and not the popup window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some more details and an example? Sounds like you need to switch window handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open the popup you probably get an additional window handle and need to change window handle to interact with the popup. This can be checked in the drivers `window_handles` attribute, and switched to by using the drivers `switch_to_window` method.

```py
# before clicking button to open popup, store the current window handle
main_window = driver.current_window_handle

# click whatever button it is to open popup

# after opening popup, change window handle
for handle in driver.window_handles: 
    if handle != main_window: 
        popup = handle
        driver.switch_to_window(popup)

print(driver.title) # Should now be the popup window
```

Comment: I was able to fix this issue with the code below, thanks.
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])

Comment: This answer is very helpful.